# Dygraphs in Shiny : Time series drawing (by the user)

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

I am having trouble finding the right function in the *dygraphs* package in R (mainly because I want to keep the amount of CSS and HTML to a minimum because I am an R user and not a web developer) to make the user interact with a plot and modify it (The Curb !) with the mouse of his computer like in this exemple :  http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/drawing
Is it already implemented in the package at all or do you need to customize the function with CSS and HTML afterwards ? If the answer is the later do you know a tutorial or something that could help me (I cannot seem to find it in here https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/index.html ) ?

Comment: https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/shiny.html?

Comment: I ran the exemples in RStudio none of them do what I want to. The interactions they have are very similar to plotly for exemple, I want the user to modify the curb in itself not to zoom in. Or maybe I am missing something user227710 ?

Comment: It is not implemented in `dygraphs` library.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer ! That was all I wanted to know !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with the package manager : it is not in his plans to implement this functionality anytime soon.
However this package remains great and we have to thank him for his incredible job.
If someone knows enough CSS and HTML and want to spend time on it I will be more than pleased to reopen this question but in the meantime I will close it.